# No data produced from map, please check source profile and make sure it matches source data. NAmespace problem in wsdl link

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex, namespace

I used wsdl link, salesforce triggering boomi and sending data.

but it is showing error: "No data produced from map, please check source profile and make sure it matches source data."

1. Initially it was showing unsupported include tag than i use wsdl=single to eliminate include tag.
2. and than targetnamespace can not be null than i use typenamespace in request profile and provide name space

After this 2 salesforce enable to generate apexcode and parse successfully and it is triggering boomi. but now it is showing this error , request profile invalid it seems , please give me suggestion what should i do?

I am attaching screenshot of request profile and wsdl link, where i need to change,

WSDL
    https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ws/soap/cal/v1/getData?wsdl=single

[image]

Comment: Are you able to share the complete WSDL? Feel free to change the endpoint URL if you don't want it called.